# Euler–Rodrigues formula in python not returning expected rotation values

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, euler-angles

I have a function that produces a rotation matrix according to the Euler-Rodrigues formula in python. However when I rotate an array by half pi it does not sit 90 degrees to the original vector and I am not sure why. If I rotate by pi or 2pi then I get the expected rotation. The code is as follows.

```
# This is my function for making the rotation matrix
def RotationMatrix(axis, theta):
    """
    This uses Euler-Rodrigues formula.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2)
    a2, b2, c2, d2 = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([
        [a2 + b2 - c2 - d2, 2 * (bc - ad), 2 * (bd + ac)],
        [2 * (bc + ad), a2 + c2 - b2 - d2, 2 * (cd - ab)],
        [2 * (bd - ac), 2 * (cd + ab), a2 + d2 - b2 - c2]
    ])

#Here I call the function to provide a rotation matrix 
#that should rotate by 90 degrees
x = RotationMatrix((0, 1, 0), (math.pi * .5))

print(x)
#Here I define my test vector to rotate
vector = np.array((3, 4, 0))

print(vector)
# Here I apply the rotation matrix (this will become a function 
# one day)
a1 = vector[0] * x[0,0] + vector[0] * x[0,1] + vector[0] * x[0,2]
b1 = vector[1] * x[1,0] + vector[1] * x[1,1] + vector[1] * x[1,2]
c1 = vector[2] * x[2,0] + vector[2] * x[2,1] + vector[2] * x[2,2]

appliedrotation = np.array((a1, b1, c1))

print(appliedrotation)

#below here I just get the dot product and magnitude so I 
#can calculate the rotation in degrees
dp = np.dot(vector, appliedrotation)
print(dp)
maga = math.sqrt(vector[0] ** 2 + vector[1] ** 2 + vector[2] ** 2)
magb =  math.sqrt(
    appliedrotation[0] ** 2 + appliedrotation[1] ** 2 + appliedrotation[2]
)
magc = maga * magb
hmm = dp / magc
hmm1 = ((math.acos(hmm)) * 180) / math.pi
print(hmm1)
```

There is a chance I am just forgetting my A-level maths vector knowledge and when rotating in three dimensions I shouldn't be getting a change of 90 degrees at half pi but I am struggling to get my head round that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider a vector in the same direction as the axis. It will stay the same when rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your manually calculated dot product is wrong here:

```
# Here I apply the rotation matrix (this will become a function one day)
a1 = vector[0] * x[0,0] + vector[0] * x[0,1] + vector[0] * x[0,2]
b1 = vector[1] * x[1,0] + vector[1] * x[1,1] + vector[1] * x[1,2]
c1 = vector[2] * x[2,0] + vector[2] * x[2,1] + vector[2] * x[2,2]
```

You want the first component of the result to be the first row of `x` dotted with `vector`, which would mean

```
a1 = vector[0] * x[0,0] + vector[1] * x[0,1] + vector[2] * x[0,2]
```

What you actually have amounts to some type of weighted sum across rows of `x` using the corresponding entry of `vector` as the weight, which is not right.

You can see this by simply computing it with `np.dot` instead of the manual matrix-vector multiplication:

```
In [17]: x
Out[17]: 
array([[  2.22044605e-16,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.22044605e-16]])

In [18]: vector
Out[18]: array([3, 4, 0])

In [19]: np.dot(x, vector)
Out[19]: array([  6.66133815e-16,   4.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00])
```

which is `(0, 4, 3)`, as expected.

Imagine drawing the vector `(3, 4)`, pointing up and to the right in the positive quadrant of a plane (since the original z coordinate is 0). If you rotate by 90 degrees around the y axis, then the vector rotates out of the page towards you until the 3-component that was previously along the x-axis is now along the z-axis (while the y-component stayed the same), meaning you're now at the vector `(0, 4, 3)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I only started learning python a few days ago and trying to remember all the maths is a struggle, this fixed everything perfectly.